# NTC interfacing with ADC Do we need a LPF after NTC

Tags: microcontroller, analog, adc, filter

I am interfacing an [NTC](https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/panasonic-electronic-components/ERT-J0EG103FA/526528?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKICUAqBaAUgBjgcQIwYGYAxAQRAF0BfIA) with an ADC present in [FS32K146HAT0MLLT](https://www.nxp.com/part/FS32K146HAT0MLLT?_gl=1*xvgc51*_ga*NjI2MzExMzUxLjE3MTAxNDIwODk.*_ga_WM5LE0KMSH*MTcxMDE0MjA4OS4xLjEuMTcxMDE0MjExOC4wLjAuMA..#/) .The circuit is given below.I was told to follow the same circuit.

This is an automotive environment.

[image]

I think filter is not required because this is  a slow analog system.A thermistor gradually responds to changes in temperature, so is a low pass filter is not really necessary.

May I know your thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thermistor's response is relatively slower, yes, but if the environment is noisy (e.g. if the traces are routed close to relatively noisy nets such as a switching node) then the noise may lead to false measurements, so a filter will be useful.

If you really want to get rid of the filter (e.g. you may want to gain some space) then you can remove R3 and place C1 across R2. Since the NTC and R2 form a voltage divider the Thevenin equivalent of the circuit will still be an RC filter. The only downside here is that the cut-off frequency will change with temperature:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXnxo4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But it's always good to follow what is recommended by the manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you.I will keep an RC filter with a cutoff frequency half that of adc sampling frequency.